# How does Flutter find Scaffold inside a modal bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet, snackbar, scaffold

I am trying to understand how Flutter finds Scaffold from inside a modal bottom sheet.

This is all what I know:

1. When Flutter opens a modal bottom sheet using `showModalBottomSheet`, it adds the BottomSheet as a child of MaterialApp rather than Scaffold.
2. But when we do ScaffoldMessenger.of(context), where context is the one provided by the builder method of BottomSheet, it is still able to find the Scaffold and render a Sanckbar when requested.
3. Earlier when I used Scaffold.of(context), Flutter would throw an error that it no Scaffold found while traversing up the tree.

Here is the code for the same:

```
void _incrementCounter() async {
    await showModalBottomSheet(
      useRootNavigator: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      barrierColor: Colors.yellow.withAlpha(20),
      useSafeArea: true,
      builder: (_) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
        expand: false,
        builder: (__, controller) => ListView(
          controller: controller,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            20,
            (index) => ListTile(
              leading: Icon(chooseIcon(index)),
              title: Text(chooseText(index)),
              onTap: () async {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(__).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Hey, try this'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _counter++;
      });
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I am using __ as the context from the builder of DraggableScrollable Sheet.

What am I missing here?

This is the inspector dialog that shows that Bottomsheet is a child of Material App

[image]

Comment: You can pass scaffold key in your bottomsheet function

Comment: @KaranMehta I am able to use the Scaffold from inside a modal bottomsheet. What I am trying to understand is how Flutter is able to find Scaffold from inside the modal bottom sheet when the bottom sheet is a child of MaterialApp rather than Scaffold.

Comment: I think it is because of the 'context' even  it is provided by builder method of Bottom Sheet but you are not using new context.

Comment: Yes I am @WasimSafdar. As you can see in the code, I am calling ScaffoldMessenger.of() using the context provided by the builder of DraggableScrollableSheet inside bottomsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scaffold inside the bottom sheet like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    backgroundColor: ColorsRes.color12,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    // showDragHandle: true,
    enableDrag: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.88,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: fieldsList.length,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [

                            // Your Code here
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: getBottomBar(),
      );
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :)
But the question is different. The  question asks, HOW does the Flutter FINDS scaffold context inside the bottom sheet?

If you see the image above, Draggable scrollable sheet is a child of Material App and not scaffold. So doing ScaffoldState.of(context), how does flutter find the scaffold state if it's not a child of scaffold?

Comment: DraggableScrollableSheet is often a child of a MaterialApp and not a Scaffold. In this case, when you try to use Scaffold.of(context) inside a widget that is not a direct child of the Scaffold, it may not work as expected because Scaffold.of(context) looks for the nearest ancestor Scaffold widget in the widget tree. If it doesn't find one, it will throw an error.

To find the Scaffold state when the DraggableScrollableSheet is not a direct child of the Scaffold, you can use one of the following approaches. and you need to pass the scaffold key